# How to split a huge string by date using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've got a pdf file turned into a huge string of over 1,000,000 characters. There are dates in the string in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want to split the string by dates into smaller ones. I tried following:

```
var sectioned = hugeString.split(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/g);
```

But it's not working. I also tried `hugeString.match()`, but no good result there.

Is it even possible to accomplish this by string functions or should I think of a different approach?

String snippet:

`....Section: 2 Interpretation E.R. 2 of 2012      02/08/2012 .....`

Comment: Remove the `^` and `$` anchors from that regex. They are needed when you want a string to be a date in its totality, but not when the string is allowed to have other text surrounding it.

Comment: Try `.split(/(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/-](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/-]\d{4}/)` - remove anchors, `g` modifier and use non-capturing groups. Wrap in `(?=PATTERN HERE)` if you need to split keeping the dates in the split chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove anchors, `g` modifier (it is redundant) and use *non-capturing* groups to avoid dates being output as well in the results. Wrap in `(?=PATTERN HERE)` if you need to split keeping the dates in the split chunks. However, if you prefer this approach, please make sure there are no optional `0`s in the pattern at the beginning, or you might get redundant elements in the result.

```js
var s = "....Section: 2 Interpretation E.R. 2 of 2012      02/08/2012 ..... ";
var res = s.split(/(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/-](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[\‌/-]\d{4}/);
console.log(res);
res = s.split(/(?=(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/-](?:0[1-9]|1[012])[\‌/-]\d{4})/);
console.log(res);
```

Note you also had a `[\/]` subpattern without `-` in the pattern while the other separator character class contained both chars. I suggest using `[\/-]` in both cases.